# Максимальная сумма подряд идущих элементов последовательности

Tags: c

Нужно написать программу на Си, которая находит максимальную сумму подряд идущих элементов последовательности. При этом нельзя использовать массивы. Последовательность считывается из файла.

Comment: @alexooo, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это известная [проблема максимального подмассива](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem):

```
double max_ending_here = 0;
double max_so_far = 0;
while (есть ещё элементы в файле)
{
    double x = <текущий элемент>;
    max_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + x);
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
}
return max_so_far;
```